# Why do I get a segmentation fault in this C++ code?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm completing problems on HackerRank and so far I've been able to do all the troubleshooting easily, but for this one I get a segmentation fault.

I looked it up online and found that it means that I'm accessing a memory that wasn't allocated to the task.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
    int N, x, a, b;
    vector<int> v;
    cin >> N;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        v.push_back(a);
    }
    cin >> x;
    v.erase(v.begin() + x-1);
    v.erase(v.begin() + a-1, v.begin() + b-2);
    cout << v.size() << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get this error? The only possible problem I can see is that I should have used a pointer or a reference somewhere but I'm still unclear as to how those work.

Comment: What values do you enter when you get the seg fault?

Comment: The N values that go into the array by using v.push_back(a);

Comment: You are using uninitialized variable `a`.

Comment: @S.M. It's initialized at the beginning. The first line of main

Comment: For a [mcve], you should replace the manual input with hardcoded values. Apart from the convenience, it makes sure that the input operations don't cause the trouble.

Comment: @JohnArg It's declared at the first line in main, at no point is it initialised.

Comment: What is the `a` on the second `v.erase` line supposed to be?

Comment: Please turn on warnings when compiling as well. The compiler would have told you about the use of uninitialized variables.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Not sure what turning on warnings means

Comment: @JohnArg Your compiler should emit warnings for dubious code (of which you have plenty). Either you are ignoring those warnings, or you have suppressed them. Most compilers have options to enable the display of warning messages.

Comment: @JohnArg I meant could you say the **actual values** that you type in when you run your program and it crashes. But it probably isn't important, your code has such serious problems that the input doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an obvious problem here

```
v.erase(v.begin() + a-1, v.begin() + b-2);
```

At no point in the program do you give `b` a value.

Neither is `a` initialised, because although you have a variable `a` in your for loop, it's a different variable from that declared at the top level in main. So both `a` and `b` are uninitialised at this point, and this probably explains your crash.